# Total placement of tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, backgrounds

I want my background picture to be placed over the body of my frame. So the header and footer is still completely free.

The picture I am using doesn't have to be scaled. It has the right size, to fit exactly between header and footer.

My problem can be solved, by either putting the top-left-corner of the picture under the header or by putting the bottom-left-corner of the picture over the footer or equivalent.

Or by "inventing" something that works like at=(current page.center)+(0,1cm) to move the picture 1cm upwards (measured from the page center)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight, width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\centering
Test
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then why are you scaling it?

Comment: When I compile your code it puts the picture in the centre, taking (I guess) half the height and the full width. How does this demonstrate the problem? What is the problem?

Comment: You mean like `([yshift=10cm]current page.center)`?

Comment: yes, but `([yshift=10cm]current page.center)` throws multiple errors

Comment: @cfr ok adding `yshift=1cm` as an option to `node` like `\node[opacity=0.3, yshift=1cm, at=(current page.center)]` works (note that 10cm is too much). If you add an answer I'm willing to accept it.

Comment: I'm a friend of deleting obsolete comments. (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/should-we-clean-up-obsolete-comments)

Comment: Can you show a MWE that includes your header and footer? What happens for frames with diffferent head heights? Frames without frametitle? Frames with a subtitle?

Comment: @samcarter my header and footer come from a non-public template, so I'm not allowed to upload them. I know, that this is only a solution which allows to specify the position manually. But right now, this works for me. (My frames all have the same head height, all a title and non a subtitle) Anyway, feel free to create a solution which somehow gets the correct coordinates.

Comment: @Ben Can you make an example with some dummy headline and frametitle? My idea would be measure the height of headline/frametitle and position the image accordingly. But as your exmaple does not have a headline "create a solution which somehow gets the correct coordinates" would require a crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I assume an height of headline and frametitle of `1.6cm`.

To get a more accurate measure of this value, you could

- be lucky and your theme adheres to the practise of beamer to store this length in `\headlight`, then you only need to add the height of the frametitle to this.
- put the content of headline and frametitle in a box and let tex measure the height of this box

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \vbox{%
        \vskip1.6cm%
        \hskip-0.5em%
        \tikz\node[opacity=0.3]{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}};%
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```